# one to many unique "set" oracle db

Tags: oracle11g, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, unique-constraint

I am not sure how to create a one to many relationship, but restrict the many items as a "set" to each unique primary key.

DB: Oracle 11g

Example:

**PK Table**:

```
CUST(PK)
100
200
```

**Valid FK Table Data**:

```
CUST(FK) | ITEM
100 | 101
100 | 102
200 | 101
200 | 102
```

**Invalid FK Table Data**:

```
CUST(FK) | ITEM
100 | 101
100 | 101
200 | 104
200 | 104
```

Any suggestions how to setup such a relationship? I'd like to limit the uniqueness so it is not possible to add a value to the FK table that violates the above "set" uniqueness.

Can this be done purely on the Oracle DB end, or must I enforce this from the accessing Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a [unique constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) with two columns: CUST and ITEM, similar to:

```
ALTER TABLE secondtable
ADD CONSTRAINT custItem UNIQUE (CUST, ITEM)
```

Create this constraint in addition to your Foreign key

Comment: That did it! Clearly I know nothing about databases :)

Answer (score 1):

this might  help you..create your tables following way....

```
create table cust_id 
           (cus_id number primary key) 
                  tablespace ts1;
  create table Valid_FK_Tabl
            (cus_id number,item number,constraints pk1 primary key(cus_id,item))
                  tablespace ts1 ;
  alter table Valid_FK_Tabl 
             add constraints fk1 foreign key(cus_id) 
                    references schema2.cust_id(cus_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for creating new tables, but since I already had them, I used cha's alter table method.